# Develop code locally, run through virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, web-development

I would like to develop on my Windows machine and have the code run and update on a CentOS virtual machine. I could probably figure out some way to do this, but I would rather use any pre-existing method, if there is one

Comment: Drag and drop it. It works great for me on both Windows and Mac OS X hosts using VMware. The guests include nearly all the major linuxes.

Comment: @noloader, I was hoping for something less manual than that.

Comment: Which programs are you using?

Comment: @mowwwalker - that's about as lazy as it gets :) I do it. What, specifically, are you trying to do? What is your current process?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

Use a [shared folder](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html), which contains your code and is used by your VM and your Host. Run the code in your VM.